# Loop divide to table column

Tags: arrays, loops, html-table, divide

I would like to print out a html table- it should divide data into x columns per row via for loop.

```
$alphabet_arr = array('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K');
```

No. of cols need to define, eg: cols= 3

No. of rows define as unlimited for now (so that whatever data excess cols will be push down to new tr, future may allow define specific row.

Then inside the table, it should be like this

```
table start
1st tbl row showing A, B, C
2nd tbl row showing D, E, F
3rd tbl row showing G, H, I
4th tbl row showing J, K, empty td
table end
```

Comment: by construct a table you mean create 2d-array? print a table? what is your final goal?

Comment: print out a html table by setting column limit, so that when fill until the column, the remaining data will go down to second row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print <table>
row_num = arr_size/col_size;
if (arr_size % col_size != 0) row_num++;
for (int i=0; i<row_num; ++i)
{
   print <tr>
   for (int j=0; j<col_size; ++j)
   {
      print <td> arr[i*col_size+j] </td>
   }
   print </tr>
}
print </table>
```